# what's the difference between create and new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did:

resources :posts

What's the difference between the 'create' and the 'new' urls?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the Rails convention `new` is used with the HTTP verb `GET` and `create` is used with `POST`.

Say you are creating a blog and you have a model object called `post`.  In the controller the `new` method will send a new post object to the view (a form).  When the user fills out the form in the view and clicks submit, the form will `POST` the data to the controller's `create` method where it will be saved.